# If $G$ is a nonabelian simple group then $G$ has at least $7$ non-normal subgroups of distinct order

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is (any) nonabelian simple group, then why has $G$ at least $7$ subgroups of distinct orders?

My question is a lemma in an article.
The proof of lemma in the article is:

> Noticing the subgroups of distinct orders are not conjugate in $G$, we calculate the number of subgroups of distinct orders of prime powers of $p$ for every $p\in\pi(G)$.
>   One more fact is that $G$ cannot have all Sylow subgroups self-normalizing, otherwise $G$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$ by Corollary in other article, a contradiction. By checking the number of prime power divisors of $|G|$ and noticing that there is at least one Sylow subgroup not self-normalizing, one can see that $G$ has at least $7$ subgroups of distinct orders.

Now I want to know, why is the number of this subgroups greater than $7$?

Comment: Is $G$, in this proof, *any* nonabelian simple group? Or are there other hypotheses?

Comment: G is any nonabelian simple group

Comment: *A priori*, I don't see. Could you post a link to the article? Also, what is π(G)?

Comment: "Note on the Solvability of a Finite Group and the
Number of Conjugate Classes of Its Non-normal
Subgroups" by Guiyun Chen and Shunmin Chen(2012)

Comment: A *link*,  if you please!

Comment: I found the abstract, for what it's worth.
http://mirrors.library.cornell.edu/ZMATH/msc/en/zmath/search/?q=an:05951294&type=pdf&format=complete

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand autors reasoninig but it can be proved by Burnside theorems.

**Theorem(Burnside)** Any finite simple group has at least $3$ prime divisior.

**Theorem(Burnside)** If $N_G(P)=C_G(P)$ for $P\in Syl_p(G)$, $G$ is $p$ nilpotent.

**Theorem(Burnside)** If $P\in Syl_p(G)$ is cyclic for a smallest $p$ dividing order of $G$,$G$ is $p$ nilpotent.

**Claim**: If $G$ is a finite abelian group then $G$ has at leats $7$ subgroups of different orders.

We know that $G$ has at least $3$ prime divisior. Let they are $p,q,r$. W.L.G assume $r$ is the smallest prime dividing order of $G$.

By, Burnside theorem we know that sylow $r$ subgroup can not be  cyclic. we have at least $2$ subgroup of order distinc power of $r$.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p$. Notice that $H<N_G(H)$ if $H$ is not sylow subgroup.(normalizer will grows in sylow-$p$ subgroups). If $H$ is a Sylow subgroup then again we must have $H<N_G(H)$ otherwise $G$ is $p$ nilpotent By Burnside.(we can assume that $H$ and $N_G(H)$ are different groups)

An let $K$ be a subgroup of order $q$.

we have $2+2+1=5$ subgroup. The left $2$ is not so hard !

Comment: by counting {e}?? whats mean?

Comment: @zahra: Trivial subgroup of $G$. The subgroup of order 1.

Comment: in question 7 is the number of non normal subgroups

Comment: You did not mention it ?

Comment: {e} is trivial subgroups which is normal but in my question 7 is yhe number of nonnormal subgroups

Comment: @zahra: Then edit your question. You did not mention it !

Comment: I think your argument gives at least $7$ subgroups. If you count subgroups of the Sylow subgroups and also the Sylow normalizers, you get at least $3$ coming from $r$ and at least two from each of $p$ and $q$. Of course you have to think about situations where two of these orders coincide! Note that for $A_5$ there are exactly $7$ such orders, so this result is best possible.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I think so.